# Chart.js - Stacked bar chart with values from the inputs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to draw a chart with chart.js. A vertical stacked bar chart with just two values.

When I hardcode the numbers as data, the graph works as expected. However, I want to get the values of two different inputs with type number fields dynamically and have them update the chart when the values of the input fields are updated.

When I try to do so, the graph doesn't work correctly. Here is the link to the fiddle I created.
https://jsfiddle.net/zissman/c9bnedy2/. And the corresponding code.

```
<form>
  <input type="number" id="calc1" onChange="updateChart2();" />
  <input type="number" id="calc2" onChange="updateChart2();" />
</form>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var data1a = document.getElementById('calc1');
  var data2a = document.getElementById('calc2');

  var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var chart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [''],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Vorjahr',
          data: data1a.value,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,255,1)',
          datalabels: {
            color: '#000000',
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'start',
            clip: true,
            formatter: function (value2, ctx2) {
              return value2 + '  %';
            },
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Ist / Soll',
          data: data2a.value,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,100,100,1)',
          datalabels: {
            color: '#000000',
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'start',
            clip: true,
            formatter: function (value2, ctx2) {
              return value2 + '  %';
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  function updateChart2() {
    var updateValues2 = [data1a.value, data2a.value];
    chart2.data.datasets[0].data = updateValues2;
    chart2.update();
  }
</script>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input fields should assign to each dataset respectively.

```js
function updateChart2() {
  chart2.data.datasets[0].data = [data1a.value];
  chart2.data.datasets[1].data = [data2a.value];
  chart2.update();
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cpgy1q?file=index.html)

Comment: Saved my day and my week, maybe my month as well. Thank you!!!!

Comment: No worries, glad to see that it helps. =D